# Why is the value of "changeco()" and "moving()" undefined? - javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying to make a animation using `js` and I got this error when I run this code:

```js
var s = document.getElementById("canvas");
var snake = s.getContext("2d");
var snakeobj;

function cannew() {
  snakeobj = new points();
}

function points() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.xspeed = 1;
  this.yspeed = 0;
  this.changeco = function() {
    points.x += points.xspeed;
    points.y += points.yspeed;
  }
  this.moving = function() {
    snake.fillStyle = "green";
    snake.fillRect(points.x, points.y, 30, 30);
  }
  snakeobj.changeco();
  snakeobj.moving();
}
points();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" style="border : 1px solid; background : black;"></canvas>
<script src="snake.js"></script>
```

I found that the "changeco()" and "moving()" are undefined by using `console.log();` please help!!

Comment: Show us your console.log call

Comment: Because you never call `cannew()`

Comment: Where should I call it?

Comment: You call `points()` instead of `cannew()`. Therefore `snakeobj` don't have any properties.

Comment: Apparently your code was edited, I noticed that you missed the opening `<html>` tag. Please fix that too.

Comment: Also, what is the point(!) of having a function that creates a new object, and reference `snakeobj` (an external object) in that function? You need to rethink your code.

Comment: Calling `cannew()` calls `points()` which needs `snakeobj` which hasn't been set to anything yet, because setting it was the second half of `cannew()`s job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You forgot the opening `<html>` tag.
2. You don't need the paranthesis in the console.log call.
3. You first have to call `cannew()`to instantiate the object.
4. You have to use `this` instead of `points`.

You can see it work in this demo:

```js
var s = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var snake = s.getContext("2d");
  var snakeobj;

$(document).ready(function(){  

  console.log("First click into the black field and then use W,A,S,D to move.");
  snakeobj = new points();
  
  window.addEventListener("keypress", myEventHandler, false);

});

function points() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.xspeed = 10;
  this.yspeed = 10;
  
  this.goRight = function() {
    this.x += this.xspeed;
  }
  this.goLeft = function() {
    this.x -= this.xspeed;
  }
  this.goDown = function() {
    this.y -= this.yspeed;
  }
  this.goUp = function() {
    this.y += this.yspeed;
  }
  this.moving = function() {
    snake.fillStyle = "green";
    snake.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 30, 30);
  }
}


function myEventHandler(e)
{
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
        
    if(keyCode == 100){
      snakeobj.goRight();
    } else if(keyCode == 97){
      snakeobj.goLeft();
    } else if(keyCode == 119){
      snakeobj.goDown();
    } else if(keyCode == 115){
      snakeobj.goUp();
    }
  
  //console.log(snakeobj);
  snakeobj.moving();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" style="border : 1px solid; background : black;"></canvas>
```

Comment: But still why is the value of points.x and points.y undefined?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. You only have to call the class methods in console.log without parentheses. Please take a look at the code now. I output `x` and `y` too now. And you have to use `this` instead of `points`.